# Why does Amazon RDS memory utilization drop and disk space utilization rises?

Tags: mysql, memory, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I encountered a problem with my Amazon RDS(db.m2.2xlarge) where DB connections spiked up and my website started responding slowly. On looking up the metrics I was not sure why my freeable memory shot up and freeable space went down.

It is worth noting that the free space went down by 22 GB, the freeable memory rose by 5GB and the swap space increased from 0 GB to 1 GB.

Has anyone encountered this before and can explain why does this happen ? Pasting the graphs below. Thanks in advance.

**Freeable Memory**[image: Freeable Memory] **Freeable Space**[image: Freeable Space] **Swap Space**[image: Swap Space] **CPU Utilization**[image: CPU Utilization] **DB Connections**[image: DB Connections]

Comment: Did you ever find anything that was causing this?

Comment: No, I could not find anything that seemed to make sense. Hence, I left it as it is and moved on.